# I can't type name in Ktouch

Tags: typing-break

I can't type name in Ktouch. The cursor is not showing and I can't type in welcome window.

[image]

I tried uninstall and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i managed to input into the field by just middle clicking on the field, this pastes whatever is in the clipboard and then the button becomes clickable

Comment: yep, sir, it worked just a moment (it passed name box), still can't type in lesson. xD  , btw, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there is a Issue with wayland,Execute the application as x11:flatpak run `--env=QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb org.kde.ktouch`
for permanent fix install Flatseal `flatpak install flathub com.github.tchx84.Flatseal` if you didn't install flathub then https://flathub.org/setup. after installing flatseal Open the flatseal goto Environment section add the variable
`QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb` [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWayz.png)

Comment: "Thank you so much! Your guidance truly worked, and I'm incredibly grateful for your help." https://imgur.com/TxhWEL5